# Jsf is not show value

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, web-applications, xhtml

I using to jsf for web app learn. But not showing value in index.xhtml . My class name is JsfBean and Named value is cdiBean. I want to call patika variable . How can I solve this problem? Is have info anyone

index.xhtml file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
   <title> JSF 2.2</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

   <h:form>
      <h:outputText value="#{cdiBean.patika}"/>

   </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

JsfBean Class

```
import jakarta.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Named;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;


@Named(value = "cdiBean")
@RequestScoped
@Getter @Setter
public class JsfBean {
    public String patika;
    public JsfBean() {
        patika="Spring Boot Eğitime Hoşgeldiniz";
        System.out.println(patika);
    }
}
```

Web.xml file

```
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         version="5.0">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your backing bean class should implement Serializable interface

Change the declaration of your backing like this

```
public class JsfBean implements Serializable{}
```

Comment: this did not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You are simply not putting the getter and setter annotations in the correct positions.
lombok appears to be for generating these methods if there is no other processing to do between the arguments to or from method and property.

```
import jakarta.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Named;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Named(value = "cdiBean")
@RequestScoped

public class JsfBean {
    public @Getter @Setter String patika;
    public JsfBean() {
        patika="Spring Boot Eğitime Hoşgeldiniz";
        System.out.println(patika);
    }
}
```

See their promotion video   https://projectlombok.org/#